# sql group by nested

Tags: sql, oracle10g

We need to find TOP 10 students (max score 500) from each section of class.

Example :

```
Section  Name   Total Score  

     A   Paul   499  
     A   Gustuv 498 
         ...upto top 10  

     B   Henrik  499  
     B   John   498   
         ...upto 10
```

Lets say it has two tables STUDENT and CLASS.

How is to possible to display the results in such a manner using sql in oracle ?

Comment: Post the DDL of the tables NAME and CLASS..

Comment: select section from class; select name, subject, score from NAME;

Comment: What fields ties NAME and CLASS table together?

Comment: it is the name only that ties them together. Instead of NAME table, we can say STUDENT table. Let me edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

I don't have your schema to test.... But you should be able to get the general idea.

```
with rank_query as (
SELECT section, name, score,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY section ORDER BY score) score_rank
FROM   myTable
)

select * from rank_query where score_rank <= 10;
```

Thanks,

Jeffrey Kevin Pry

Comment: The query would fail with an error because score_rank is not a defined column of myTable rather a derived column. Make the query without the where clause as an inline query/view and remove the GROUP BY clause as you are using RANK already

Comment: Jeffrey: Now it looks fine.. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` (depending on what you mean by "top 10") analytic functions.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/RankDenseRankFirstLastAnalyticFunctions.php